# Arranging divs vertically but wrapping if need be

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to figure out a way of lining up divs vertically on the left hand side of the screen but if the browser windows is resized (i.e. made smaller) then I want the divs to be re-arranged so that they start filling a 2nd column.

In addition I want to enforce a minimum number of rows of divs so for example if you resized the browser and made its height quite small you wouldn't get the divs re-arranged taking up a lot of columns.

I'm pretty certain I would do this with jQuery but I have no idea where to start looking and would be very grateful for any pointers.  In my research so far I have come across a plugin called Masonry but it is not clear if this will do what I require.

Thanks very much

Ed

Answer (score 0):

Masonry is a good framework and i think the answer to you question.
Take a look at the CellsByColumn method : http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/cellsbycolumn.html

You can also see an codepen exemple here : http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/qAlEy

```
layoutMode: 'cellsByColumn',
cellsByColumn: {
  columnWidth: 110,
  rowHeight: 110
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt div to devices screen using css media queries

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions - in the end I decided to make an AJAX request which sent the browser height to a server side script each time the browser was resized.

My server side script then did a little bit of algebra to create an HTML table with a certain number of rows and columns based on the browser height.  I then put an icon in each of the table cells.